# Is it "in jargon" or "on jargon"?

Tags: prepositions

I am choosing which preposition to use before jargon – "in jargon" or "on jargon"?
I know that it's usually "in %language%": "in english", "in hawaiian", "in mexican", but google translator gives "on" for jargon and "in" for %language% jargon ("in nigerian jargon").
Google shows about 300 000 results for both "in jargon" and "on jargon" search requests within quotes.

The full phrase I wish to write is:
*However, this is not enough (“not sufficient”, **in/on??** jargon of math books).*

Comment: It needs a definite article: ' ... in the jargon of math/s textbooks.'

Comment: _"not sufficient", as they say in math books_.

Comment: Please learn how to use Google: Google does not show 50,000 results - it shows 241 examples of **"in jargon"** - we know this as on the final page (the third page) of results it says *"In order to show you the most relevant results, we have omitted some entries very similar to the 241 already displayed.*" "in jargon" = in the language of jargon -- Google shows 235 examples of **"on jargon"** = on the subject of jargon.

Comment: Please, please, please, please: **Fix your caps**. All those languages need a capital letter. **Proper phrasing** +  in math book jargon OR the jargon of math books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for instance "*speaking on German*", "*speaking on Spanish*" or "*speaking on slang*"  would never be said, "*speaking on jargon*" should not ever be tolerated if one wanted to preserve to the language the greatest possible consistency  and ease of use, and so, this form is never used to mean "using jargon to express oneself"; this can be deduced from an examination of [this page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on+jargon%22&lr=lang_en&safe=active&tbs=lr:lang_1en,sbd:1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMvovU9e7vAhUpCWMBHS2iDGUQpwUIJA&biw=1920&bih=1005&dpr=1).

([ref; 1](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/TechGnosis/kdJnBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22in+jargon%22&pg=PA35&printsec=frontcover)) Maybe yes, maybe no; what's important is that electricity's uncanny play leads us to ask not how it works or how it can be captured in jargon, but what it is. This is the kind of natural philosophy that can set one wondering about the whole.

It is normal to find a lot of hits for "on jargon" because this prepositional phrase is used often enough, but with different meanings ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+jargon%2Con+jargon&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20jargon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20jargon%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cin%20jargon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20jargon%3B%2Cc0)). The meaning is then quite regularly "*about*" (speaking about jargon, lecturing on jargon, etc.) or "*supported by*" (rely on jargon, depend on jargon, etc.) or the meaning of a relation of action of the verb to what this action  bears upon (work on jargon).

([ref. 2](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/On_the_Art_of_Writing/GLPCDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22on+jargon%22&pg=PT120&printsec=frontcover)) Further, it was against this loose adaptation of words to thought and to things that we protested in our interpolated lecture on Jargon, which is not so much bad writing as the avoidance of writing.

([ref. 3](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Army_Organizational_Effectiveness_Journa/UqsrAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22on+jargon%22&pg=RA21-PA2&printsec=frontcover)) Professionals who depend on jargon can be dangerous , and as part of their education they should be taught some manners .

([ref. 4](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/English_Teaching_from_A_to_Z/BSUjAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22on+jargon%22&dq=%22on+jargon%22&printsec=frontcover)) Some ideas for a unit of work on jargon could include : ( 1 ) Have the students collect lists of jargon from newspaper and magazine articles : legal , political , sporting , and so on . ( 2 ) Have them make a list of jargon of their parents ' ( brothers ' ...

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard the phrase "on jargon". Perhaps it's an American phrase, I don't know; but I'm certain I've never heard a British English speaker say it.

Comment: Examles of "on jargon" and of "in jargon" in British publications are found by Ngrams: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+jargon%2Cin+jargon&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true  For example: "My argument in this book is not dependent on jargon"

Comment: That isn't an example of "on jargon". That's an example of "depend on". I depend on friends for lots of things, but the structure is "(depend on) (friends)", not "(depend) (on friends)", and it wouldn't make sense to present this as an example of "on friends".

Comment: [...] never heard the phrase "on jargon". It is most definitely not American per se. It's English and it depends what one **wants to say**. A treatise on business jargon versus in business jargon, one would say or write x. All Englishes.